# Авто загрузка данных из файлы на страницу

Tags: html, javascript, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, скрипт загрузки из файла содержимого без перезагрузки страницы, есть один скрипт, но мне кажется, он постоянно перезагружает страницу, что сказывается на трафике.

```
     <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.0.min.js'></script>
     <script type='text/javascript'>
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
            $('.chat').load('chat-include.php').fadeIn('slow');
        }, 100);
     </script>
```

Comment: может вместо setInterval использовать setTimeout. Вам же один раз нужно загрузить данные?

Comment: нет, нужно, чтобы в этот небольшой чат данные загружались, например каждые 5 секунд, это тут и происходить, правда, кажется постоянно обновляясь, что влияет на трафик, и сервер порой просто не работает

Comment: @ivanforpw может быть стоит просто делать последовательные запросы (даже через определенные промежутки времени), нежели как у вас - каждые 100мс?

Comment: тоже про это подумывал, но вот вопрос, неужели нет других скриптов, и любой будет делать запросы? значит, серверы контакта и других чатов испытывают такие же нагрузки?

Comment: @ivanforpw там же не глупые люди сидят :-) Сейчас глянул - vk делает продолжительные запросы (~25 секунд). И там, судя по всему не php используется. Говорю уже в сотый раз: при правильной реализации приложения нагрузки будут минимальны. Но "правильно" у каждого своё :-)

Comment: хорошо, лучше тогда оставлю для начала без автообновления... вы мне давно хотели тут помочь, посмотрите, пожалуйста
http://hashcode.ru/questions/163107/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-radio-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5

Comment: @ivanforpw обновил сообщение

Answer (score 1):

Смотреть в сторону [Comet](http://javascript.ru/AJAX/COMET), [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), [WebSocket](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) и прочих подобных технологий

Comment: Не ради спора, а чисто из интереса: почему вот vk использует ajax запросы с, скажем так, полу-comet запросами? Что-то в этом есть. Плюс заметил странные у них функции, вида ce, de. Как-будто это так удобно. Странные там ребята сидят. У них походу схема long poll.

Comment: Возможно им так действительно удобней..  Тем более, что запросы там очень маленькие по объему

Comment: @Photon да я бы не сказал, что запрос легкий. Чего стоят только одни кукисы :-) Если так посчитать, то у них один запрос весит 250байт. 
Соответственно 1gb данных это 4млн запросов. В день пишут, что 11биллион запросов. Хотя я думаю эту цифру можно смело на 2/3 умножать.